# vertical split in Chrome DevTools sources to view multiple files at once

Tags: ide, google-chrome-devtools, setuptools

As described in the title I would like to have a vertical split in Chrome DevTools inside the sources panel, to view multiple files in one screen.
I am searching the equivalent of alt+shift+2 of sublime Text editor for the ones that are aware. It looks like this:
[image: grid view in sublime]

I would like the same effect here I am hust makeing this question to see if you guys are aware of doing that on chrome or firebug tools:

[image: where I would like to have verical split]